Closed-form formula for supremum
Would there be a way to compute a closed-form of
$\sup_x \frac{\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i c_i)^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i c_i) + c_{n+1}}$ where $x_i > 0$, $c_i \geq 0$. All variables are real numbers.
If $c_{n+1} = 0$, then it's easy to show that it's simply $\sqrt{n}/n$. However, I wonder if anyone knows a way for this more general form.
I'm looking for this to compute the Lipschitz constant of a function. So the formula above is the norm of a gradient. The original formula is $\log(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i c_i) + c_{n+1})$.

I claim that
$$ \sup_{x} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i} (x_{i}c_{i})^{2}}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i}c_{i} + c_{n+1}} = \sup_{y} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_{i}^{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_{i} + c_{n+1}} $$
where $k$ is the number of $c_{i} > 0$. Basically this is a reparameterization of the problem -- we take $y_{i} = c_{i}x_{i}$ and note that this has the same constraint as $x_{i}$ (namely $y_{i} > 0$) unless $c_{i} = 0$, in which case $y_{i} = 0$. However, the zero values add nothing to either sum.
Now, if $c_{n+1} > 0$, we can simplify further by dividing it out of the top and bottom. In other words, we note that
$$ \sup_{y} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_{i}^{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_{i} + c_{n+1}} = \sup_{z} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} z_{i}^{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} z_{i} + 1} $$
where $z_{i} = y_{i}/c_{n+1}$. Again, we have the same constraint that $z_{i} > 0$.
Maximizing this is a bit more involved, but probably the way I would go about it is taking the gradient of it (or rather the square) and then setting it equal to zero. Since the maximum can't occur at $z=0$ (the only point where the function is really ill-behaved), this should give a closed-form solution.
